# Can i use an if statement for a player name? [ROBLOX]

Tags: roblox

I am on Roblox again, and I wanna make a script where when a part is touched, if the player name is lorenzoomh, set the brickcolor to green. But if not, set it to red. my current code:

```
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(igottouched)
    if game.Players.LocalPlayer.Name == "lorenzoomh"  then
        script.Parent.BrickColor = BrickColor.Green()
    else
        script.Parent.BrickColor = BrickColor.Red()
    end
end)
```

which doesnt work btw

Comment: What doesn't work? Is there an error? Does nothing happen? Is your code in a LocalScript and what is the script's parent?

Comment: parent is serverscriptservice theres no error just nothing happens and its not a local script

Comment: A player cannot Touch ServerScriptService, is this supposed to be for a part in the Workspace?

Comment: it was then i moved

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question, "can I use a player's name in an if-statement" is yes. Your problem is that the LocalPlayer doesn't exist where you're trying to use it from.

See the [docs for Players.LocalPlayer](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Players/LocalPlayer) :

> This property is only defined for LocalScripts ... as they run on the client. For the server (on which Script objects run their code), this property is nil.

You need to access the Player object a different way. The Touched event on a Part gives you access to the other object that touched it. You can use that to check if the other part belongs to a player's character model.

```
local target = game.Workspace.Part

-- listen for a player touching a block
target.Touched:Connect( function(otherPart)
    -- check that the thing that touched is a character model
    local character = otherPart.Parent
    local isCharacter = character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") ~= null
    if isCharacter then
        -- the character model name is usually the name of the player so use that
        if character.Name == "lorenzoomh"  then
            target.BrickColor = BrickColor.Green()
        else
            target.BrickColor = BrickColor.Red()
        end
    end
end)
```

The [Players service has a method](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Players/GetPlayerFromCharacter) for correlating a character model with a Player object specifically if a simple name check is not sufficient for your use case.